# how to get second max date in postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I have following situation where i need to get several values between two invoices date.

So query is giving data based on invoices now what i need to do is for some values fetch data between this invoice date and last invoice date

already tried ways
1) sub query will easily solve this but as i have to do this for 4-5 column and its a 15 gb database so that's not possible.
2) if i go like this

```
left join (select inv.date ,inv,actno from invoice inv) as invo on invo.actno=act.id and invo.date < inv.date
```

then it will give all the data less then that date but i need only one data that will be less than main invoice date.

3) we can not get second max value in subquery of from clause because outer invoice is not grouped so it might be max or midlle or least .

4) we can not send values of other table in subquery of join table.

ex

```
create table inv (id serial ,date timestamp without time zone);

insert into inv (date) values('2017-01-31 00:00:00'),('2017-01-30 00:00:00'),('2017-01-29 00:00:00'),('2017-01-28 00:00:00'),('2017-01-27 00:00:00');

select date as d1 from inv;
 id |        date         
----+---------------------
  1 | 2017-01-31 00:00:00
  2 | 2017-01-30 00:00:00
  3 | 2017-01-29 00:00:00
  4 | 2017-01-28 00:00:00
  5 | 2017-01-27 00:00:00

(5 rows)
```

I need this

```
 id |date                 |date                 | id 
  1 | 2017-01-31 00:00:00 | 2017-01-30 00:00:00 |  2
  2 | 2017-01-30 00:00:00 | 2017-01-29 00:00:00 |  3
  3 | 2017-01-29 00:00:00 | 2017-01-28 00:00:00 |  4
  4 | 2017-01-28 00:00:00 | 2017-01-27 00:00:00 |  5
  5 | 2017-01-27 00:00:00 |
```

I can't do subquery in select as database is big and need to do this for 4-5 column

UPDATE 1

I need this from same table but using it twice in FROM clause as my requirement is that I need several data joined from invoice table and then there is 4-5 column in which I need things like sum of amount paid between last and this invoice.

So I can take both invoice date in subquery and get the data between them

UPDATE 2

lag will not solve this

```
select i.id,i.date, lag(date) over (order by date) from inv i order by id ;
id |        date         |         lag        
----+---------------------+---------------------
1 | 2017-01-31 00:00:00 | 2017-01-30 00:00:00
2 | 2017-01-30 00:00:00 | 2017-01-29 00:00:00
3 | 2017-01-29 00:00:00 | 2017-01-28 00:00:00
4 | 2017-01-28 00:00:00 | 2017-01-27 00:00:00
5 | 2017-01-27 00:00:00 | 
(5 rows)
Time: 0.480 ms
test=# select i.id,i.date, lag(date) over (order by date) from inv i where id=2 order by id ;
 id |        date         | lag 
----+---------------------+-----
  2 | 2017-01-30 00:00:00 | 
(1 row)
Time: 0.525 ms
test=# select i.id,i.date, lag(date) over (order by date) from inv i where id in (2,3) order by id ;
 id |        date         |         lag       
----+---------------------+---------------------
2 | 2017-01-30 00:00:00 | 2017-01-29 00:00:00
3 | 2017-01-29 00:00:00 |
```

it will calculate on the data it will get from the table in that query it is bounded in that query see here 3 has a lag but could not get it cause query is not allowing it to have it   ....something in left join needs to be done so the lag date can be taken from same table but calling it again in from clause Thanks Again buddy

Comment: `select date as d1, lag(date) over () d2 from inv;`

Comment: @VaoTsun I think you need an `over(ORDER BY date)`

Comment: You question's title is not consistent with your expected output.

Comment: @Gurv Maybe not, but for a first time post, I think he did a very good job explaining the problem.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza  taking in account he has single column, should work without specifying order by? not sure though

Comment: @Vao no, you need to add order by and you should add that as answer.

Comment: @VaoTsun You always need [**order by**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) `All of the functions listed in Table 9-56  depend on the sort ordering specified by the ORDER BY clause of the associated window definition. Rows that are not distinct in the ORDER BY ordering are said to be peers; the four ranking functions are defined so that they give the same answer for any two peer rows.`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Thanks for pointing this

Comment: thanks guys but this will not solve my problem 
i need this from same table but using it twice in FROM clause 
as my requirement is that i need several data joined from invoice table and then there is 4-5 column in which i need things like sum of amount paid between last and this invoice
i will update my example accordingly thanks all of you once again

Answer (score 3):

Like here?:

```
t=# select date as d1,
           lag(date) over (order by date) 
    from inv 
    order by 1 desc;


         d1          |         lag
---------------------+---------------------
 2017-01-31 00:00:00 | 2017-01-30 00:00:00
 2017-01-30 00:00:00 | 2017-01-29 00:00:00
 2017-01-29 00:00:00 | 2017-01-28 00:00:00
 2017-01-28 00:00:00 | 2017-01-27 00:00:00
 2017-01-27 00:00:00 |
(5 rows)

Time: 1.416 ms
```

Comment: thanks Juan but this will not solve my problem it will surely get data as in my example but will not give me the id which i need .I have updated my question i did miss some point in it.

Comment: @VijayVerma: just add `lag(id) over (order by date)` to get the id as well

Comment: lag will not solve this   
test=# select i.id,i.date, lag(date) over (order by date) from inv i where id in (2,3) order by id ;
 id |        date         |         lag         
----+---------------------+---------------------
  2 | 2017-01-30 00:00:00 | 2017-01-29 00:00:00
  3 | 2017-01-29 00:00:00 | 


it will calculate on the data it will get from the table in that query it is bounded in that query see here 3 has a lag but could not get it cause query is not allowing it to have it